# what happens when you call a program from the terminal?

Tags: linux, pip

meaning. I call a program. Example 'pip' (since I am having trouble with pip) and what does the Linux system do to find that program?

I'm having trouble with a pip installation and im trying to understand what happens under the hood when I type pip or any program into the terminal and press enter.

My hope is this allows me to fix the issue.

if you wish to know what issue I am having it is `ImportError: No module named 'pip'`

Comment: This question would be better suited for [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Since *this question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).*

Answer (score 0):

Linux will search for all available directories listed in the environmental variable PATH, and if it find `pip` from any path, it will try to execute it. And then in case the file `pip` has executable permission for the user, system will execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

In general the shell searches through the directories listed in the `PATH` variable to find a file with the name you typed in. If you want to find out which file the shell is actually trying to run, on a unix-like system (read not windows), run `which pip`. I believe the windows equivalent is `where pip`, but don't quote me on that.

The specific error you are encountering, however appears to be the result of python being run something like `python -m pip` which means Python, please run the module named `pip`. Given that some file exists named `pip` on your system that tries to run `pip`, I am guessing one of two things is happening.

1. Either you have deleted some of the files somehow, in which case you should attempt to reinstall `pip`
2. Or you have changed which python is the default python, and you don't have a `pip` module in the python you are using now.

To test the last theory, try running `which python` and if there is a `2` in the path, then run `python3 -m pip` to see if the pythons got mixed up. Conversely if your are on a system that uses python3 by default, you will see a `3` in the result of the above command, and you can try `python2 -m pip`.

Hope that helps clear up the mess that is Python versioning.

Comment: thank you. I have been working on this for half the day.

I did which python and I got
/usr/bin/python

I did which pip and I got

/usr/local/bin/pip 

My assumption is that because python and pip are in two different locations my pip is breaking. Is this correct?

Comment: That is entirely possible. I would recommend opening `/usr/local/bin/pip` which should be a text file, and see if you can figure out what it wants.